# Pywin32 Excel write limits?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, vba

I'm using pywin32 and the common way to write range to excel, by getting some range objects and then writing to it with

```
 range.Value=my_data
```

(it's all the same syntax as VBA)

Now, if I have a set of fairly large cells (>6000 chars) and I write them out all at once by setting the Value of a range object, then it sometimes throws an exception at one of these cells (but writing the cell by itself would work).

Do you know any limits with Excel and write range operations that I should consider?

The exceptions look like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    e.write_area([tuple("a"*10000 for i in range(20))]*20, sheet="Tabelle1")
  File "excel_com.py", line 209, in write_area
    self.get_range(col, row, col+num_col-1, row+num_row-1, sheet=sheet).Value=data
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 550, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

or

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    e.write_area([tuple("a"*1000 for i in range(20))]*10000, sheet="Tabelle1")
  File "excel_com.py", line 209, in write_area
    self.get_range(col, row, col+num_col-1, row+num_row-1, sheet=sheet).Value=data
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 521, in __setattr__
    debug_attr_print("SetAttr called for %s.%s=%s on DispatchContainer" % (self._username_, attr, repr(value)))
MemoryError
```

where excel_com.py is a module of mine. Whether these exceptions come up depends on column-, row-, cell-size of the data written. However I don't know what's the system behind that :(

Comment: What exception?? Show the **FULL** traceback and error message.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a fixed size limit for transferring an array to a range. It depends more on the memory required for the array, RAM, etc. If there is any chance the amount of data is large, it's best to break up the array into chunks and write them one at a time.